# how to combine server and client to work together as one program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets, server

is their a function that i can check if there is incoming connection or not to the server ( inside While Loop )?

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   
PORT = 8888 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

while 1:

    ##### IF there is request to server Do #####
          conn, addr = s.accept()
          print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

          data = conn.recv(1024)
          reply = 'OK...' + data
          conn.sendall(reply)

    ##### Else Do something else like print for example #####
          print 'Nothing yet'
conn.close()
s.close()
```

what i want to do is to check if there is no request to my server i will do something else.
is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a such function.

From [`man accept`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> In order to be notified of incoming connections on a socket, you can
>          use select(2), poll(2), or epoll(7).  A readable event will be
>          delivered when a new connection is attempted and you may then call
>          accept() to get a socket for that connection.

In python you can use [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) combined with the timeout parameter:

```
import select

# somewhere in a while loop
timeout = 0
incoming_connections, _, __ = select.select([s], [], [], timeout)
if incoming_connections:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    ...
else:
    ...
```